# Assigning JSON in a GraphQL type in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, graphql

I am calling a report API with Nodejs which gives me a JSON response. The api can be called with different ID (in this case different report id). For example:

```
  https://report.domain.io/report/1
  https://report.domain.io/report/2
```

and so on. As the id is different in different time it will give me different responses. The attribute/s name will be different. So I cannot map it in a GraphQLObjectType. For example if the JSON response is following:

```
[
    {
        "modelbrand": "Sony",
        "modelcode": "F3111",
        "avg_free_storage": 225401514
    },
    {
        "modelbrand": "Sony",
        "modelcode": "F3111",
        "avg_free_storage": 224547840
    }
]
```

Then I can map it with GraphQL like following:

```
Report() {
    return new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "Report",
        description: "This represents report",
            fields: () => ({
                "modelbrand": {type: graphql.GraphQLString},
                "modelcode": {type: graphql.GraphQLString},
                "avg_free_storage": {type: graphql.GraphQLString}
            })
    });
}
```

cause I know the attributes are fixed. But if the attribute/s name like modelbrand, modelcode changes to something else (obviously it will be different for different report) then I cannot map it in GraphQLObjectType. In that case, I need a another type (which should be a JSON type) to map these responses. Unfortunately, it is not available as primitive type for GraphQL. I am not finding any custom/scalar type or node library to solve this problem. There is a solution in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353161/how-to-use-graphql-type-json-package-with-graphql) but seems like it is not working.

Could I please get a solution for that? An Nodejs example will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you do the type mapping with attributes with underscores like above `avg_free_storage`?

Answer (score 9):

Please refer this [graphql-type-json](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json). This can be used as custom scalar json type.

In schema file

```js
scalar JSON

type User {
  id: ID!
    userDetails: JSON
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): User
}
```

In resolver file

```js
import GraphQLJSON from 'graphql-type-json';
import {User} from './connectors';

const resolvers = {

  Query: getUser(_, args) {
    return User.find({
      where: args
    });
  },

  JSON: {
    __serialize(value) {
      return GraphQLJSON.parseValue(value);
    }
  }
}
```

As of the latest version you can define JSON like this in your resolver

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: getUser(_, args) {
    return User.find({
      where: args
    });
  },
  JSON: GraphQLJSON,
}
```

This may help you

Read Docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json)